# how to keep curl from deleteing log.txt when adding new entry?

Tags: bash, curl, logging

**I am trying to do**: create a bash script that downloads the Ubuntu iso and a file from my own ftp server. Then do a traceroute to my server and save route/date and avg speed of the two downloads to log.txt.

**Where i am stuck:**

This seems to do okay

```
curl -o test.avi http://hostve.com/neobuntu/pics/Ubu1.avi  2> test.log
```

Sadly it removes the previous content of test.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `>`, you are removing the previous data. If you want to append data, use `>>`:

```
curl -o test.avi http://hostve.com/neobuntu/pics/Ubu1.avi  2>> test.log
```

From [Bash Reference Manual #3.6 Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections):

> **3.6.2 Redirecting Output**
>
> Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the
>   expansion of word to be opened for writing on file descriptor n, or
>   the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified. **If
>   the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is
>   truncated to zero size.**
>
> The general format for redirecting output is:
>
> ```
> [n]>[|]word
> ```
>
> **3.6.3 Appending Redirected Output**
>
> Redirection of output in this fashion causes the file whose name
>   results from the expansion of word to be opened for appending on file
>   descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not
>   specified. If the file does not exist it is created.
>
> The general format for appending output is:
>
> ```
> [n]>>word
> ```